# Crankset replacement and compatibility

Tags: crankset, chainring

I got a new gravel bike and the crankset has only 42T which is a bit less thank ideal for a flat country like Denmark. I tried to find compatible cranksets, but I didn't find any relevant info except "they are standardized, but there are multiple standards".

My the crankset model is `Forged Alloy 1x10, Hollow CrMo Spindle, Narrow Wide 42T` as specified by the producer (https://www.marinbikes.com/bikes/2022-gestalt-x10). How may I find compatible cranksets? Can you please recommend me a compatible 50-54T crankset?

EDIT: I've found on it "Samox ET40 E13", but very few references on the internet. May I change only the chainring?

Comment: The number of teeth is dictated by the chainrings, which are typically a separate piece of metal from the crank, and are just bolted to the cranks. So you should be able to replace just the chainring which will be much cheaper and easier (less complicated compatibility checking) than replacing the whole crankset. Do you think your chainrings are not detachable from the cranks?

Comment: As an example of chainrings detached from the cranks, you can have a look at this previous question of mine: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/83606/do-these-chainrings-need-replacing  It's a different topic, but you can see pictures of chainrings off the cranks.

Comment: One thought not worth an answer: Have you tried riding gravel on that bike yet? I know you said Denmark is very flat. However, we do ride slower on gravel. You may find the gearing to be adequate.

Comment: @WeiwenNg yes, just went out with it today and I mostly used the smallest and second smallest cogs (25-30Km/h) on gravel and only the smallest cog on asphalt (28-34Km/h). With a 50-54T chainring I would expect to use the middle-lower cogs instead of stressing the smallest one all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bike is designed around a 1x groupset which very often limits what crank size options are available.  The smaller chainring is often combined with wider chainstays to give bigger tyre clearance.

[From the Marin website](https://www.marinbikes.com/bikes/family/gestalt-x):
*"The Gestalt X is made to expand your horizons even further beyond roads. We extended the possibilities of the Gestalt by adding generous tire clearance, lowering the stand over, using solely one-by drivetrains, adding dropper post routing, and tuning the geometry for more adventurous riding. This is the drop bar bike for the rider looking for singletrack no matter what the occassion, the perfect bike to ride the road both to and from the trail and cut through unexplored places to find new routes."*

The first thing to do is contact Marin customer support or the shop where you bought the bike and find out what the maximum supported chainring size is.  42T might already be the biggest possible.

Another alternative if you have not ridden the bike yet (or if the shop offers some sort of limited time satisfaction guarantee) is to return the bike and swap for something that supports a 2x chainset

Comment: [This image](https://jnsn.imgix.net/globalassets/product-images---all-assets/marin-2021/bi002167_1-gloss-chrome~blue~black.jpg?w=2000&auto=format&q=70&fit=max) certainly appears to provide evidence that the bike probably can't support a chainring much larger than a 42T.  Note the apparent "scooped out" area in the chainstay to provide clearance for the chainring.

Answer (score 4):

That crank almost certainly uses 3-bolt direct mount chainrings, a de facto standard based on SRAM direct mount cranks. You can probably confirm that by looking at the backside of chainring.

Getting a 44t or 46t chainring to replace the stock one is easy, but what's in question is whether the bike has clearance for them. It probably doesn't or is borderline. This is a different bike in the line, but it appears to be the same frame and also a 42t:

[image]

On some bikes there's a more tenable path to go to 10t rear, but that doesn't apply here in anything close to a cost-effective way. You could change to a double, but that also means basically changing everything (cranks, FD, left lever, RD, cassette) so isn't practical.

Comment: If this is the same Samox crankset as on the closely related  DSX models, then the chainring is not separately replaceable (according to Marin's advice). The entire crankset will need to be replaced.

Comment: @Szabolcs That image sure *looks* like a chainring bolted to a five-arm (or maybe an assymetric four-arm *a la* Shimano) spider from the inside to me.  Maybe it's not the same?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The image in this answer is not of the Gestalt X10. Based on the images and description, the X10 has the same crankset as the DSX 2. Marin customer support told me that "Unfortunately the DSX 2's Samox cranksets do not have replaceable chainrings. The chainring is 'swaged' directly onto the crankset. However the chainring material is chromoly steel, so the service life should be very long, but in the event of a crash, chainring swap or other issue, the crankset would need replacement."